# java 2 PHP translation

Tags: java, php, translation

I have this type code written in Java:

```
public static String asHex(byte[] buf) 
{
    StringBuilder strbuf = new StringBuilder(buf.length << 1);
    for (byte aByte : buf) {
        if (((int) aByte & 0xff) < 0x10) {
            strbuf.append('0');
        }
        strbuf.append(Long.toString((int) aByte & 0xff, 16));
    }
    return strbuf.toString();
}
```

Is this the same as base64_decode in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

if you have time the easiest way to find out would be to run an identical string through your function and the PHP function and see if they come out with the same result. 
Or if you really have some time spare read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Examples) and see if you can work it out.

EDIT: after a bit more looking at it appears to be just converting a byte Array to a hex string which is as you have pointed out is not base64 encoding.

I think the PHP function equivalent of what its doing is [bin2hex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php)

Comment: I'm not especially good in Java, I just need to rewrite this code in PHP. As far as I understand function is changing integer values in string to hex values... I'm guessing that this is not base64_decode :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi as @James said : bin2hex would do :

```
<?php
 $str = "Hello world!";
 echo bin2hex($str) . "<br />";
?>
```

would produce same as

```
static public void main(String args[]) {
    String str= "Hello world!";
    byte[] x = str.getBytes();
    String s = asHex(x);
    System.out.println (s);
}

public static String asHex (byte buf[]) {
    StringBuffer strbuf = new StringBuffer(buf.length * 2);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
        if (((int) buf[i] & 0xff) < 0x10)
            strbuf.append("0");
        strbuf.append(Long.toString((int) buf[i] & 0xff, 16));
    }
   return strbuf.toString();
}
```